# Javascript - array of custom object initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, initialization

How can I initialize an array of custom objects in `javascript` to prevent the error `"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"`?

**component**

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {

  myArray: MyObject[];

}
```

**view**

```
<div *ngIf="myArray.length > 1">Size is greater than 1</div>
```

The code above rightly gives the mentioned error. What is the right way to initialize the array? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given only the type of your field. You also need to initialize it to refer to something

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {

  myArray: MyObject[] = [];

}
```

Also you have different name in the template, I think it is only typo

```
<div *ngIf="myArray.length > 1">Size is greater than 1</div>
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Why?

Comment: you have no elements, and he need 1?

Comment: Why do you think that he need 1? I don't think he put the full template to work with this. It is only a part of his template. There may be another logic also to push into this items. So actually we can't say what he want to do with that template

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Thanks

Comment: SurenSrapyan yes, it was a typo. Your answer is correct, thanks. Álvaro Touzón the array is filled dynamically later in the code, that's why I need to check the size. Thanks to you too.